# Mysql - Como obtener multiples registros en una sola consulta?

Tags: mysql, pdo

En la aplicacion que estoy desarrollando, ahora estoy trabajando en la parte de recuperar contraseña mediante una busqueda avanzada, es decir, el usuario para iniciar sesion tiene la opcion de recuperar su contraseña simplemente ingresando su correo electronico, luego el sistema le enviara un codigo de seguridad para autorizar el cambio de contraseña y asi sucesivamente, la segunda opcion es de que el usuario puede que no se acuerde cual es su correo electronico, en ese caso tiene una opcion de realizar una busqueda avanzada ingresando su nombre, apellido, fecha de nacimiento y su genero (Masculino, Femenino), atravez de esos datos se hace una busqueda en la base de datos tratando de identificar que registros contiene esos datos. A lo largo de la vida del sistema puede que 2 o  mas personas tengan exactamente el mismo nombre, apellido, fecha de nacimiento y genero, lo que trato de hacer es de que a travez de una consulta pueda obtener todos los registros que coincidan con los datos solicitados, para ello tengo la siguiente consulta hecha en php utlizando PDO:

```
public function obtenerDatos($tag, $nombre, $apellido, $fecha_nacimiento, $genero, $correo_electronico){
        try {
            switch ($tag) {
                case 'Email':
                    $this->clase_dbconexion = new dbconexion();
                    $conexion = $this->clase_dbconexion->conectar();
                    $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE correo_electronico = ? AND estado = 1");
                    $consulta->execute([$correo_electronico]);
                    $conexion = $this->clase_dbconexion->desconectar($conexion);
                    return $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                break;

                case 'DatosCliente':
                    $this->clase_dbconexion = new dbconexion();
                    $conexion = $this->clase_dbconexion->conectar();
                    $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE nombre = ? AND apellido = ? AND fecha_nacimiento = ? AND genero = ? AND estado = 1");
                    $consulta->execute([$nombre, $apellido, $fecha_nacimiento, $genero]);
                    $conexion = $this->clase_dbconexion->desconectar($conexion);
                    print_r($consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
                    return $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                break;

                default:
                    # code...
                    break;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $exception) {
            echo('Se produjo un error al obtener los datos del cliente: ' . $exception->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Talvez se preguntaran porque tengo un `switch` en la funcion obtenerDatos(), pues como habia mencionado anteriormente, el usuario al tener 2 formas de poder recuperar su contraseña necesariamente se requiere 2 consultas para poder identificar quien es el usuario que esta solicitando cambiar su contraseña, el primer caso del switch se da cuando el cliente conoce su correo electronico y lo ingresa, el segundo caso es cuando el usuario no conoce su correo electronico y solicita una busqueda avanzada atravez de su nombre, apellido, etc. En el segundo caso es donde debo obtener mas de un 1 registro si es que existen usuarios que tienen el mismo nombre, apellido, etc.

Para realizar estas pruebas ingrese en mi base de datos 2 usuario con los mismos datos y la consulta solo me devuelve uno.

Comment: ¿todas las condiciones establecidas en tu consulta delimitadas por los operadores `AND` se cumplen?

Comment: Si, ya hize la prueba varias veces y de diferentes formas, me sigue devolviendo  un solo registro cuando en realidad hay 2 con los mismos datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucion: Leer la variable `$consulta` con un `while` para obtener los datos:

```
public function obtenerDatos($tag, $nombre, $apellido, $fecha_nacimiento, $genero, $correo_electronico){
    try {
        switch ($tag) {
            case 'Email':
                $this->clase_dbconexion = new dbconexion();
                $conexion = $this->clase_dbconexion->conectar();
                $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE correo_electronico = ? AND estado = 1");
                $consulta->execute([$correo_electronico]);
                $conexion = $this->clase_dbconexion->desconectar($conexion);
                return $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            break;

            case 'DatosCliente':
                $this->clase_dbconexion = new dbconexion();
                $conexion = $this->clase_dbconexion->conectar();
                $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE nombre = ? AND apellido = ? AND fecha_nacimiento = ? AND genero = ? AND estado = 1");
                $consulta->execute([$nombre, $apellido, $fecha_nacimiento, $genero]);
                $conexion = $this->clase_dbconexion->desconectar($conexion);
                while ($row = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        var_dump($row);
                }
                return $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            break;

            default:
                # code...
                break;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $exception) {
        echo('Se produjo un error al obtener los datos del cliente: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }
}
```